# Why would JS allow this function to be declared?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I have a question about decalaration of JS function.
I declared a function as follows:

```
create=(name,agfdf,gender)=>({name,a,gender});
(name,agfdf,gender)=>({name,a,gender})
```

the argument passed is agfdf, but the output does not contain agfdf. The function acutally works:

```
input: create("P",3,"M")
output: {name: "P", a: 3.6, gender: "M"}
a: 3.6
gender: "M"
name: "P"
__proto__: Object
```

I do not understand how this would work. Could anyone of you explain? Thanks a lot!

Comment: A verbose way of writing the same code (that might be a more obvious indicator of behavior) is `function create(name, a, gender) { return { name: name, a: a, gender: gender }; }`

Answer (score 0):

this type of function is called arrow function in js. 
it is es6 syntax to declare function

```
let a = ()=>{return 1;}
let b = value=>{return value;}
let c = (value1,value2)=>{return {value1,value2};}
```

in your js

```
create=(name,agfdf,gender)=>({name,a,gender});
```

you are taking 2nd parameter as agfdf but returning a. which might be initialized somewhere in your code

Comment: thank you for your answer. If I had not initialized a before this declaration, it would generate an error right?